# HOW TO WHERE $var IN filde SQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This my database

```
ID ++++++album
1 ++++++ 1,2,10,5
2 ++++++ 3,10,5
3 ++++++ 6,8,9
4 ++++++ 10
```

I want to show id album = 10
I use this code but it not work   please help me.

```
$Show=10;
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE $Show IN (album)";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma separated strings aren't a very efficient way of storing data, it makes it really hard to use indexing well.

That said, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to make the query simple;

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(10, album) > 0;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20796/2).